# List of highest scores- how to differentiate your score in the list

Tags: php

I am working on simple game.

When user view scores of all users I want his score to be in different color. How can I do it?

So far I have just list of all scores from highest score to lowest

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY score DESC;";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>

<HTML TABLE>

<?php
}

mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: if $row['player_ID'] == $currentuser['ID'] sort of thing?

Comment: Step 1: Switch to [mysqli](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test whether the player in the row is the current player, and set a class. Then use CSS to assign a color to that class.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $class = $row['player'] == $current_player ? 'class="highlight"' : '';
    echo "<tr $class>";
    // code for rest of table row
    echo "</tr>";
}
```